# How do I enable tap gestures for UIButtons inside a Stack View in the UINavigation Bar with iOS 11 and Swift 3

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, ios11

I have 3 `UIButton`s inside a `UIStackView` in the `UINavigationBar`. The buttons act as a title but are a date/select date, next date and previous date button.

The buttons each perform a different function based on a `touchUpInside` event connected to a `@IBAction` function. Everything is coded in Swift 3.

They buttons were working just until upgraded Xcode and my iPhone over the weekend so that they run on iOS 11. Now the buttons all appear frozen, although they still work if I take them out of the Stack View (and keep them in the `UINavigationBar`).

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 11 manages the subviews of navigation and toolbars differently. For example, I've noticed on migrations and upgrades that bar button items containing custom views (particularly where those custom views use stack views) can be visible but the containing stack view is zero-height, meaning that touches are ignored.

Check how you are creating custom views for your bar button items and ensure that at runtime everything has a non-zero frame. You may need to add more constraints. Use the view debugger and examine the frames of everything in the navigation bar first so you can work out what to amend.

Comment: That appears to be the issue. Thanks!